# Want My page.php file to display different pages categories Loops

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

In my page.php file, i'm aiming to have different categories' loops for different pages using this conditioner:

```
if (is_page(array('pagename1', 'pagename2'))) {
}
```

But when I placed the loop below inside the 'is_page' braces, I got blank page

```
<?php
    $newsposts = get_posts('cat=4');

    foreach($newsposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="newsbox2 newsboxcolor1">
            <div class="newsbox3pix boxeq">
                <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array() );
                    }else { 
                 ?>
                     <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/noimage.jpg" alt="no image">
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="newstitle boxeq2">
                <span class="matchtime"><?php the_time();?><br></span>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
            <span class="fa fa-comments cmnt"> <?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></span>
     </div><!--newsbox2-->
  </div>
        </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How do I go about integrating these so that i can have all my pages conditionals inside one file? I will appreciate any suggestion here. Cheers

Comment: Please provide full code with your `if case is_page`.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are not used for pages they are used for posts.

The code  `get_posts('cat=4')` will fetch all posts under that category.

If you will write this code in page.php then in all pages created from backe-end , you will get the posts of specified category.

Comment: yes i want to publish posts from a specific category into the page. I want to create different rules for different pages inside a single page.php instead of individual page (page-name.php). Do you understand?